# mysql subqueries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have a `mysql query` that uses a `subquery` to select all users that are not in group 10 in the group_member table. the query works fine on `MYsql` workbench and brings back the expected results. However when I run it in a `PHP script` it's not runnning the subquery part, in stead it's just bringing back a list of all users.

Anyone got any ideas what's going on here or perhaps an approach that doesn't need the subquery?

```
include('config.php');    

$server = $cfg->dbhost;

$link = mysql_connect($cfg->dbhost, $cfg->dbuser, $cfg->dbpass);
$select = mysql_select_db($cfg->dbname); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE usr.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT member FROM mahara.group_member WHERE mahara.group_member.group='10')";
echo '</br>' . $query . '</br>';
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['id'] , ' ' , $row['username'] , ' ' , $row['firstname'] , ' ' , $row['lastname'] , ' ' , $row['email'] , '</br>';   

}
```

Comment: Did you try running the subquery on its own? Does it return any records?

Comment: The query itself looks fine; what you can double check is if you're actually testing the same query at the same MySQL host and the same database. I don't know about your setup, but I know that I have multiple test database for a given production database :)

Comment: It could me a missing link identifier in the mysql_select_db, which means that it is using last link opened by mysql_connect() is assmued. But you already opened it just before calling mysql_select_db. I would still give it a try: $select = mysql_select_db($cfg->dbname, $link);